# JQuery Datepickers to POST

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-plugins

I have asked this before, but my meaning was not understtod...

My Situation is that I need the Start and End JQuery datepicker on the webpage, and it must... #1 - The End Date must always be greater then Start Date... #2 - The date range must POST data from MySQL to create a table of the data on the webpage.

How can I change the script below (that has #1 working of the tasks needed above), to also POST the information from MySQL via PHP back to the HTML DIV.

See the example of what I am building on my webpage [here](http://www.pvmonitor.000a.biz/sw-report.php)

```
1.<script type="text/javascript">          
$(function () { 

    var start1 = $('#start1'); 
    var end1 = $('#end1'); 

    start1.datepicker({ onClose: clearEndDate }); 
    end1.datepicker({ beforeShow: setMinDateForEndDate }); 

    function setMinDateForEndDate() { 
        var d = start1.datepicker('getDate'); 
        if (d) return { minDate: d } 
    } 
    function clearEndDate(dateText, inst) { 
        end1.val(''); 
    } 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There was another jQuery function on your site that you didn't include:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $.post('report.php', {
        start: $('#start1').val(), 
        end: $('#end1').val()
    }, 
    function(data) {
       $('#genreport').html(data).show();
    });
});
```

You probably already know this, but you will also need to reformat and filter/verify the date inputs in your report.php page. I hope this helps. I didn't realize this question was so old until I just posted it. HAH! Just ignore this, as you probably have it working already.